# Entity Framework InvalidOperationException when updating an item

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get an `System.InvalidOperationException` error which states:

> Additional information: Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for
>   property 'state' because the entity of type 'BatteryItem' does not
>   exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or
>   Attach method of DbSet.

Haven't I done exactly this? That is my method below:

```
public void UpdateBatteryState(BatteryItem batItem, BatteryState state)
{
    try
    {
        batItem.state = state.ToString();
        context.BatteryItem.Attach(batItem);
        var entry = context.Entry(batItem);
        entry.Property(x => x.state).IsModified = true;

        Save();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even want to set the IsModified property manually? EF has change tracking built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from that info you should do it this way:

```
public void UpdateBatteryState(BatteryItem batItem, BatteryState state)
{
    try
    {

        context.BatteryItem.Add(batItem);
        batItem.state = state.ToString();

        context.SaveChanges()
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: Updated. There's no `bi`, it's `batteryItem` only.

`state` is not a model, it is `varchar` in the DB, `BatteryState` is enum.

Comment: context.BatteryItem.Attach(batItem);

change it to

context.BatteryItem.Add(batItem);

Comment: Why `Add`? I don't want to put new object in the database, but to update the current one?

Comment: `Add` won't put a new object in the database. `SaveChanges()` will.

Comment: @Nikola, sorry i miss that one,
have you try removing entry.Property(x => x.state).IsModified = true;
and change it to entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by calling `EntityState.Modified` first then disabling modifications for the properties after that, something like this:

```
db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(obj).Property(x => x.Password).IsModified = false;
```

Comment: @DownVoter, can you explain the problem?